# CMake Could NOT find GMP

Tags: cmake, arm, debian, apt-get, gmp

I am trying to cross-compile CVC4, but GMP could not be found. I use the following guide for the installation: http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/wiki/Developer%27s_Guide

When I run `./configure.sh production` I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find GMP (missing: GMP_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindGMP.cmake:10 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:356 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

However, I have installed `libgmp3-dev:armel` and `libgmp10:armel`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev:armel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libgmp3-dev:armel is already the newest version (2:6.1.2+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install libgmp10:armel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libgmp10:armel is already the newest version (2:6.1.2+dfsg-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
```

Are there other gmp packages I need to install or is it necessary to specify the installation location as a parameter for the `./configure.sh` command.

Comment: I wonder if installing the native package might trick a broken cmake script into working...

Comment: » cross-compile CVC4 « : The dependencies must be present for [target - architecture] .... either installed as packages, or cross-compiled before compiling CVC4.

Comment: The needed dependency GMP is installed for the target architecture (:armel). 
`libgmp3-dev:armel is already the newest version`. What do you mean by native package? The version without :armel or installation from source?

Comment: They have a configure script just to call cmake, they are asking for trouble... And that makes it harder to use the standard CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE to specify how to cross-compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify the installation location as a parameter for the `./configure.sh` command:

```
./configure.sh --gmp-dir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi
```